# Problema al renderizar una img o un video dentro de un condicional ng-if-else

Tags: html, angular, typescript

La idea principal del presente código es que basado en la detección tanto del navegador como del dispositivo pueda renderizar un video o una imagen; anexo el codigo .html, .ts, .service.ts
Tengo el siguiente problema de que no se me esta renderizando nada que este contenido dentro del condicional (ng-if-else) 'ng-container' 'ng-template' del html, en el DOM cuando inspecciono la consola me esta llegando como un código que no se esta mostrando. En el caso de que quito el condicional del html y solo dejo la 'img' o el 'video' si se me esta renderizando lo que muestre, agradecería de su ayuda si es que estoy haciendo algo mal, gracias.

```js
import { ConnectedPosition } from "@angular/cdk/overlay";
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { AppConfig } from "@app/data/services/tools/app-config.service";
import { BrowserDetectionService } from "@app/data/services/tools/browserDetection/browser-detection.service";

@Component({
  selector: "melp-mia",
  templateUrl: "./mia.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./mia.component.scss"],
})
export class MiaComponent implements OnInit {
  icons: any = this.appConfig.icons;
  isOpen: boolean = false;
  isDeviceApple: boolean = true;
  positions: ConnectedPosition[] = [
    {
      originX: "center",
      originY: "center",
      overlayX: "center",
      overlayY: "center",
      weight: 0,
      offsetX: 0,
      offsetY: 0,
      panelClass: "mia-overlay",
    },
  ];

  constructor(
    private appConfig: AppConfig,
    browserDetectionService: BrowserDetectionService,
  ) {
    if (browserDetectionService.isSafari()) {
      console.log('El navegador es Safari en un dispositivo Apple.');
      this.isDeviceApple = true;
    } else {
      console.log('El navegador no es Safari o el dispositivo no es Apple.');
      this.isDeviceApple = false;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  isOpened() {
    this.isOpen = !this.isOpen;
  }

}
```

```css
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class BrowserDetectionService {

  constructor() { }

  isSafari(): boolean {
    const userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
    const vendor = navigator.vendor;

    const isChromeOrAndroid = /chrome|android/i.test(userAgent);
    const isSafari = /safari/i.test(userAgent);
    const isAppleDevice = typeof vendor !== "undefined" && vendor.indexOf("Apple") === 0;

    return isSafari && !isChromeOrAndroid && isAppleDevice;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-button"
  (click)="isOpened()"
  cdkOverlayOrigin
  #trigger="cdkOverlayOrigin">
  <div class="container-bubble-avatar">
    <img [src]="icons.mia_base" alt="icon-mia" style="height: 150px;">
    <div class="wrapper-avatar">
      <ng-container *ngIf="isDeviceApple; else elseTemplate">
        <img src='assets/img/mia/mia-transiction-ios.mov'>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-template #elseTemplate>
        <video class="chat-logo"
          loop
          name="media"
          autoplay
          muted>
          <source src='assets/img/mia/mia-transiction.webm' type="video/webm">
        </video>
      </ng-template>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<ng-template cdkConnectedOverlay
  [cdkConnectedOverlayPositions]="positions"
  [cdkConnectedOverlayOrigin]="trigger"
  [cdkConnectedOverlayOpen]="isOpen">
  <iframe id="iframe_chatbot"
    style="display: block;"
    allowtransparency="true"
    src="https://www.nnn.com/chatbot"
    frameborder="0"
    class="browser-iframe">
  </iframe>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Qué pasa si cambias `isDeviceApple` por `isSafari`, igual ten en cuenta de que Safari solo existe para dispositivos Apple así que tal vez quieras remover esta parte del código.

Comment: Pasa que la validación en el .ts la estoy haciendo con la variable `isDeviceApple` la cual dependiendo de su estado quiero mostrar una img o un video y si requiero hacer la validación porque necesito mostrar en un dispositivo apple

Comment: No me queda claro, no te está mostrando ni `if` ni el `else` ??  (ninguno de los 2), o te muestra uno ?? que navegador estas usando?

Comment: Por otro lado podrías probar quitar los `if` y quedarte solo con el `video` y dentro de él agregas otro `source` (es decir te quedas con 2), el primero de ellos lo apuntas al `.mov` y el segundo lo dejas tal como está....haber si funciona de esa manera

Comment: si exacto no me muestra ninguno de los, y eso que lo forzo a que me muestre el .webm ya que estoy desde Chrome y en ese navegador si debería de mostrar dicho video... también probe quitando el condicional y si me muestra la img o el video, estoy viendo que mi problema radical es en el condicional que lo que sea que agrego dentro de el no lo esta renderizando, no se si se deba también al overlay que uso de material

Comment: Y si usas doble `*ngIf` con negación `!`?

Comment: no nada.... ya solucione!!!! tuve que en el controler dentro de la deteccion del navegador agregar js puro y agregar clase 'display: none' en ambos tanto en el video como en la img